# How to get select of one table with order and range of second related by ForeignKey table?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(SomePlacesModel, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField('Event Name', max_length = 20)
    event_date= models.DateField('Event Date')
    ...


class Result(models.Model)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField('Event Name', max_length = 20) # Cache from Event
    result = models.FloatField('Result')
    some1 = ....
    some2 = ....
```

I need to get QuerySet of Result ordered by Event.event_date for last Month(Week, etc..)
Something like (but this don't work..):

```
res = Result.objects.select_related('event__event_date').filter(some1 = something1, some2 = something2).order_by('event_name')[range:]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is supposed to do. You can order on the related field with:

```
res = Result.objects.filter(
    some1=something1, some2=something2
).order_by(
    'event__event_date'
)
```

If you want to only retrieve the `Result` for `Event`s of the last week, you can filter with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import timedelta

res = Result.objects.filter(
    some1=something1, some2=something2,
    event__event_date__gte=now().date()-timedelta(days=7)
).order_by(
    'event__event_date'
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! What's that i really needed.. Thanks!